# TeamCity RESTful API guest login sometimes doesn't work

Tags: rest, build, teamcity

I'm using the guest auth for TeamCity REST calls, however every once in a while it response to a request for json (or xml) with the HTML from the login screen.

Has anyone else experienced this? have any pointers?

Comment: while it is very unlikely that this bug is your fault, please post your login code so we can see for sure

Comment: It's a bit intermittent, but I'll have a go at putting something self contained together. In the mean time, if you're really keen, you could run the code from source at github.com/tobyweston/radiate (but I wouldn't expect you too!)

Answer (score 0):

I also experienced such a behavior, depending on data, which I request from Rest - when I am requesting agent configuration, it is not allowed to be served to guest (at least, this seems so, starting from 7.1 till 8.0.2)

Comment: I don't request agent information, just project and build info. It's intermittent but I can't pin point it to specific resources :(